# Finding the interval of solutions of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to determine the interval in which the solutions are sure to exist.

$$y^{(4)}+4y'''+3y=t$$

Can someone please help me with how to go about such problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of any homogeneous ODE of the type:
$$ c_n y^{(n)}+\ldots + c_1 y' + c_0 y = 0 \tag{1}$$
are entire functions, hence they are defined over any interval of the real line.

Obviously, if $y(x)$ is a solution for $(1)$ then $y(x)+\frac{x}{c_0}$ is a solution for:$$ c_n y^{(n)}+\ldots + c_1 y' + c_0 y = x \tag{2}$$
and vice-versa, and the function $\frac{x}{c_0}$ is entire, too.

Comment: Is the definition of entire function a function over any real line?

Comment: @MarionCrane: much, much more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: But we haven't defined them in class in any way. I mean I haven't taken a course on complex analysis

Comment: @MarionCrane: then replace the word "entire" with "everywhere defined and $C^\infty$".